# Power Apps select first item of combo box

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a Power Apps application that has a combo box within the form. I'm using a combo box because the options available to a user are based on another list. On the "SecondList" there are two fields, Title and User. I filter the user based off a people picker called "SearchUser" then bring back all the "Title" in the drop down. I would like to select the first item in the drop down as the default, which is different for each user.

```
DefaultSelectedItems = ThisItem
Default = LookUp("SecondList",User.DisplayName = SearchUser.Selected.DisplayName)
Items = Filter("SecondList",User.DisplayName = SearchUser.Selected.DisplayName)
SearchFields = ["Title"]
```